# How to manipulate method names as strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have a migration with 14 string columns, which I have named after:
`q1, q2, q3...q14`
Is there any way that I can iterate through those as literals? something like:

```
i=1
while i<15 do
  Something.each do |t|
    t.q+#{i}=...
  end
end
```

..yeah, I hope you do not stick to the code, just to get the idea...

Isn't there a DRY method for this?

Thanks a bunch..

Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..15).each do |i|
  Something.each do |t|
    t.send "q#{i}=", value
  end
end
```